# web3.eth.accounts returns only one object

Tags: truffle

I'm new to crypto development and trying to follow a hello world tutorial here:
https://github.com/alto-io/hello-crypto

I was able to install and launch truffle, execute the contract migrations, launch the test page and connect it to my Metamask account. The balance on my truffle development network reads 0.
According to the tutorial, I should be able to send myself some ETH by doing the following in the truffle console:

```
 web3.eth.sendTransaction({web3.eth.accounts[0], to:web.eth.accounts[1], value: 10000})
```

but `web3.eth.accounts` is not even returning an array, it returns only one object.
Any advice on how to send myself some test ETH in this tutorial would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial is 3 years old. Ethereum is changing very fast so the packages.

```
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  const accountSender = accounts[0];
  const accountReceiver=accounts[1]
```

Comment: Thx, it made a difference. But opened up a whole bunch of more questions that deserve a separate question.

Comment: i would recommend you do not follow that tutorial. it is a very old tutorial.

Comment: Thx. I'm not hell-bent on completing this particular tutorial, I will appreciate any newer suggestions.

Comment: follow this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ&t=113313s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org  32 hours. 1 moth task for you. it s beginner friendly

Comment: Good tutorial by Patrick indeed. Thx for this.